# Scala dot product very slow compared to Java

Tags: java, arrays, scala, math

I am very new to Scala and I would like to translate my Java code with the same performance level.

given n float vectors and an additional vector, I have to compute all n dot products and get the maximum one.

Using Java is pretty straightforward for me

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int N = 5000000;
    int R = 200;
    float[][] t = new float[N][R];
    float[] u = new float[R];

    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0;i<N;i++) {
        for (int j = 0;j<R;j++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                u[j] = r.nextFloat();
            }
            t[i][j] = r.nextFloat();
        }
    }

    long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
    float maxScore = -1.0f;

    for (int i = 0;i < N;i++) {
        float score = 0.0f;
        for (int j = 0; i < R;i++) {
            score += u[j] * t[i][j];
        }
        if (score > maxScore) {
            maxScore = score;
        }

    }

    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - ts);
    System.out.println(maxScore);

}
```

The compute time is 6 ms on my machine.

Now I have to do it with Scala

```
val t = Array.ofDim[Float](N,R)
val u = Array.ofDim[Float](R)

// Filling with random floats like in Java

val ts = System.currentTimeMillis()
var maxScore: Float = -1.0f

for ( i <- 0 until N) {
  var score = 0.0f
  for (j <- 0 until R) {
    score += u(j) * t(i)(j)
  }
  if (score > maxScore) {
    maxScore = score
  }

}

println(System.currentTimeMillis() - ts)
println(maxScore);
```

The above code takes more than on second on my machine.
My thought is that Scala has no primitive array structure such as float[] in Java, and is replaced by a collection. The access at index i seems to be slower than the one with primitive array in Java.

The below code is even slower:

```
val maxScore = t.map( r => r zip u map Function.tupled(_*_) reduceLeft (_+_)).max
```

which takes 26s

How should I efficiently iterate over my 2 arrays to compute this ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can use Arrays in Scala... where/how are `t` and `u` defined in the Scala example?

Comment: Oops, missed it!
just updated the post

Comment: @ogen not related to your problem, but as a side note, `0 until N` is more idiomatic than `0 to (N-1)`

Answer (score 23):

Well, sorry to say but the odd thing here is how fast your Java implementation is, not how slow your Scala one is - 6ms for traversing 10 billion (!) cells sounds too good to be true - and indeed - **you have a typo** in the Java implementation that makes this code do much less:

instead of `for (int j = 0; j < R;j++)`, you have `for (int j = 0; i < R;i++)` - which makes the inner loop run **only 200 times instead of 10 Billion**...

If you fix this - the Scala and Java performance are comparable.

This, BTW, is actually an *advantage* of Scala - it's harder to get `for (j <- 0 until R)` wrong :)

Comment: Holy! It took me a few seconds to notice the typo after you explained it **in your answer**. Nice catch!

Comment: LOL :D I started reading generated scala byte code, because it was so strange to me. And that was just a typo in the java code :D :D :D

Comment: I totally agree this is an advantage of Scala. This is also why i and j should actually not be used together in any language as for-loop indices. :) x and y are usually much easier to see these kinds of things.

Answer (score 3):

The real problem was just a typo (like Tzach Zohar mentioned), but if you would like to improve the performance, then you can do it in more impretive way:

```
var i = 0
while (i < N) {
  var j = 0
  var score = 0.0f
  val t1: Array[Float] = t(i)
  while (j < R) {
    score += u(j) * t1(j)
    j += 1
  }
  if (score > maxScore) {
    maxScore = score
  }

  i += 1
}
```

This code snippet runs about 10-20% faster than the for-comprehension version.

OR ! you can use "par" to make the first array parallel and use while loop inside map:

```
val maxScore = t.par.map({
  arr =>
    var score = 0.0f
    var j = 0
    while (j < R) {
      score += u(j) * arr(j)
      j += 1
    }
    score
}).max
```

This code runs 2-3 TIMES faster on my machine than the java version!
Try it yourself! :) Good luck